# How should I persist timestamps in SQL DB if app uses NodaTime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, n-tier-architecture, nodatime

I want to start using NodaTime in my application to manage times, instants and general time localization.

Sometimes I persist timestamps to a SQL Server 2008 database. I had traditionally used datetime2 fields in UTC. These timestamps will be created using Noda. It seems that this date conversion to Noda's `Instant` may be undesirable.

What type should I use to persist them?

If I use a non-integer in SQL then I have potential conversion issues between my App layer and my DAL. However, if I persist the integer Noda instant I will have a logical coupling between the same layers... and I will not be able to perform simple date aggregations in SQL without bringing it into the app layer or CLR.

Noda makes the case that instants can't reliably be described in UTC, since certain times never occurred in UTC.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A `datetime2` is a perfectly acceptable and normal SQL type to store an `Instant`.  Use the `Instant.ToDateTimeUtc` method to get a `DateTime`, then store that in SQL as normal.  Likewise, you can use the `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc` method when retrieving the value from SQL.

Alternatively, you could use a SQL `datetimeoffset` type if you wanted to be explicit that the values are UTC based (the offset will always be zero).  There are `ToDateTimeOffset` and `FromDateTimeOffset` methods on `Instant` you can use.

You said:

> Noda makes the case that instants can't reliably be described in UTC, since certain times never occurred in UTC.

I think perhaps you're caught up in the wording in [the user guide](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/concepts.html).  I can see how it might lead you down that line of thinking.  While it's true that logically an `Instant` doesn't represent UTC, it certainly can be reliably *described* in terms of UTC.  It could also be described in some other terms, as long as those terms were unambiguous.

The point that the user guide is making is that other values that *aren't* in UTC could still be converted to an `Instant`.  For example, I might have an `OffsetDateTime`, or a `DateTimeOffset` that has a *different* offset than zero, and it still could be adjusted back to zero to form an `Instant`.  Likewise, I might have a `ZonedDateTime` that's assigned to the UTC time zone, or some other time zone, I can still get back to a single universal `Instant` without loss of fidelity.

The same *cannot* be said of `DateTime` (unless it has `DateTimeKind.Utc`), or of `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, etc.  None of those are unambiguously a single instant in time.

As far as the other mappings:

```
Noda Time      | .NET BCL                   | SQL Server
---------------|----------------------------|------------------------------------------
Instant        | DateTime or DateTimeOffset | datetime2 or datetimeoffset
OffsetDateTime | DateTimeOffset             | datetimeoffset
LocalDateTime  | DateTime                   | datetime2
LocalDate      | DateTime                   | date
LocalTime      | TimeSpan                   | time
Duration       | TimeSpan                   | int or bigint (Ticks, TotalSeconds, etc.)
Period         | String                     | varchar
ZonedDateTime  | DateTimeOffset + String    | datetimeoffset + varchar (or a UDT)
```

Comment: UDT = [User-Defined Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/clr-user-defined-types?view=sql-server-ver15)